# Como substituir a propriedade obsoleta 'tag' no componente 'router-link' do Vue.js por slots com escopo?

Tags: vue.js

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Vue.js na versão 3 e me deparei com um aviso de depreciação no console referente ao uso da propriedade "tag" no componente router-link.

O aviso é o seguinte:

```
51:13  error  'tag' property on 'router-link' component is deprecated. Use scoped slots instead  vue/no-deprecated-router-link-tag-prop
```

Aqui está o trecho de código onde uso o router-link:

```
<router-link
        v-for="subItem in item.subItems"
        :key="subItem.label"
        :to="subItem.route"
        tag="li"
        class="p-2 hover:bg-gray-700 text-slate-300"
      >
        <a class="submenu-link">{{ subItem.label }}</a>
      </router-link>
```

Eu gostaria de entender melhor como posso substituir o uso da propriedade 'tag' por slots com escopo, conforme sugerido pelo aviso de depreciação.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No seu caso, a propriedade "tag" está sendo usada para envolver o router-link em um elemento `<li>`. Para migrar para a abordagem de slots com escopo, você pode ajustar o código da seguinte maneira:

```
<router-link
  v-for="subItem in item.subItems"
  :key="subItem.label"
  :to="subItem.route"
  class="p-2 hover:bg-gray-700 text-slate-300"
>
  <!-- Utilize um slot com escopo para definir o elemento -->
  <template #default="{ navigate, href }">
    <li>
      <a class="submenu-link" :href="href" @click="navigate">{{ subItem.label }}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
</router-link>
```

Aqui, o slot padrão (#default) é usado com o objeto desestruturado { navigate, href }, que contém as propriedades necessárias para criar seu link. Dentro do slot, você pode personalizar a estrutura do link, neste caso, envolvendo-o em um elemento `<li>`. Certifique-se de manter as funcionalidades essenciais, como o @click="navigate" para lidar com a navegação.

Dessa forma, você substitui o uso da propriedade "tag" pelo uso de slots com escopo, mantendo a flexibilidade e personalização desejadas. Se tiver mais dúvidas ou precisar de esclarecimentos adicionais, estou à disposição.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).